# Apache Nutch - Modify Queue of Links to be Crawled

Tags: java, web-crawler, nutch

I have Apache Nutch 2.0 source ported to my project and can modify & build it directly. From what I've read the -topN argument determines how many of the top scoring links in that depth/page will be queued. Actually the available resources online are confusing to me which leads me to my first question:

1. Does `-topN` correspond to the number top scoring of links to be taken **per depth**? Or is it **per page**?

And my second:

2. Do these topN links queued **in priority** with other queued topN links from other page/depth? For example `topN = 2`, 1 seed URL, for the 2 crawled pages from the seed URL, are the links taken from this depth aggregated then sorted? Or only intra-page links are sorted? This assumes though that `topN` is per page.

What I want to do is change the breadth-first behavior of Nutch. I want the top-scoring links to be crawled first, regardless of which depth they came from. From what I understand, Nutch crawls all seed URLs first, then crawls all `topN` links from `depth=1`, then `topN` links from `depth=2` and so on... What I want to do is:

- crawl all seed URLs first
- then crawl the top-scoring link.
- extract the outlinks in that top-scoring page
- queue the links to a PriorityQueue
- Dequeue the current top-scoring link, and so on...

Which leads me to these questions:

3. Is it possible to insert logic to follow the crawl behavior described above? Basically change web traversal to a hybrid of breadth-first and depth-first and always traverse to the highest scoring link.
4. Will I be able to do this concurrently?

Answer (score 0):

TopN is used in GenerateJob of Nutch to get Top N highest ranking score URLs to be fetched in FetchJob. It is not the crawling depth per page.
You can change the depth by modifying the value of `<name>http.content.limit</name>` in the nutch-site.xml file.